# How to shrink the page talbe size of a process?

Tags: linux, mongodb, memory-management

mongodb server map all db files into RAM. Along with size of database becoming bigger, the server will has a huge page table which is up to 3G bytes.

Is there a way to shrink it when the server is running?

mongodb version is 2.0.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongodb will memory-map all of the data files that it creates, plus the journal files (if you're using journaling).  There is no way to prevent this from happening.  This means that the virtual memory size of the MongoDB process will **always** be roughly twice the size of the data files.

Note that the OS memory management system will page out unused RAM pages, so that the physical memory size of the process will typically be much less than the virtual memory size.

The only way to reduce the virtual memory size of the 'mongod' process is to reduce the size of the MongoDB data files.  The only way to reduce the size of the data files is to take the node offline and perform a 'repair'.

See here for more details:
 - http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Excessive+Disk+Space#ExcessiveDiskSpace-RecoveringDeletedSpace

Comment: the page table memory in Linux kernel can't be paged out

Comment: Why are you concerned about the page table size?  It's a rounding error relative to the virtual memory size.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are asking to do something that the MongoDB manual recommends not to: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/ulimit/ in this specific scenario. Recommended however does not mean required and it is just a guideline really.

This is just the way MongoDB runs and something you have got to accept unless you wish to toy around and test out different scenarios and how they work.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to reduce the used memory of the process. You could use the `ulimit` bash builtin (before starting your server, perhaps in some `/etc/rc.d/mongodb` script) which calls the [setrlimit(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) syscall

Comment: This is simply not correct -- if you try to limit the max used memory via 'ulimit', it won't work.  You can use 'cgroups' if your kernel and distro support them.